# Run WMIC command across network

Tags: command-line, wmic

Instead of typing this in a command prompt one at a time:

wmic /node:ipaddress /user:administrator /password:mypassword bios get serialnumber

How can I run that against one entire subnet and output to a text document? Since I do this every couple months to verify our inventory of computers, I would assume there would be a much of easier way I could put this in a batch script instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may put a list after `node:`  `node:ip1,ip2,ip3`, or use a file `node:@file` - so just put all your ip addresses into a file and then run:

```
wmic /node:@nodes.txt /user:administrator /password:mypassword /output:out.csv bios get serialnumber /format:csv
```

That assumes user/password is the same on all machines.

Comment: Is there a way to list any consoles in the output file that failed? Response I get from some is "RPC unavailable" or something like that, I want to know which ones I have to go back and check because of that.

Comment: @C-dizzle You could redirect stderr to file eg. with ` 2>log.txt` (you may add it before `wmic` or append at the very end of cmdline and then analyze that. You may also want to add `/failfast:on`

Comment: I must not be doing that part right, can you give me an example on how to append that to my command?

Comment: `2>log.txt wmic /node:@nodes.txt /user:administrator  /password:mypassword /output:out.csv bios get serialnumber /format:csv` or `wmic /node:@nodes.txt /user:administrator /password:mypassword /output:out.csv bios get serialnumber /format:csv 2>log.txt` (both should be single lines)

Answer (score 2):

A for loop with a file redirection will work, although you might want to let it sit and run for a while if you have more holes in your node set (in otherwords, can't resolve the IP in the loop)

`(FOR /L %s IN (1,1,254) DO wmic /node:192.96.1.%s /user:administrator /password:pass bios get serialnumber) >> c:\results.txt`

If you plan to put this in a batch file, replace the `%s` with `%%s`.  That is all.